# How to add a custom field to the contacts in android?

Tags: android

I want to add a custom field to any new contacts created in the Android programmatically. Say for example birthday?

Please help me in this regard.

Comment: Aren't you accessing the contacts via a content provider?You should be checking the [Contacts Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html) API .

Comment: What do you mean by custom field ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want your custom field to be clickable and to be able to view it from an activity?

If so, you would need to created a synchronization service between an `Authenticator` and a `SyncAdapter`.

Check this project, where the code adds new account with custom field, which can be viewed in some activity: https://github.com/nemezis/SampleContacts.